# Call function from function into remote host through bash script is not working

Tags: bash, function, shell, remote-host

I am writing a bash script to log in the remote host and call multiple functions through it.
Calling `install_prelibrary` from ssh remote script and calling other two functions from this.
Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/shell/config.sh

install_prelibrary () {
  wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/download/v2.0.0/eosio_2.0.0-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb --no-check-certificate > /dev/null 2>&1;
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                printf "\n\nError downloading Ubuntu Binary file\n\n"
                exit 0;
  else 
                install_cdt
                create_wallet_and_keys
  fi
}

install_cdt(){
   #some commands
}
create_wallet_and_keys(){
   #some commands
}

SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; $(declare -f) ; install_prelibrary"
for i in ${!genesishost[*]} ; do
        printf "\t=========== node ${genesishost[i]} ===========\n\n"
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${password}}
        sshpass -p ${password} ssh -l ${username} ${genesishost[i]} "${SCR}"
done
```

> config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

username=abc
password=abc
genesishost=(192.168.*.*);
```

When I run this script using `bash main.sh`, first of all, `create_wallet_and_keys` is getting called. I don't know why? As I am not calling this function manually anywhere. Followed by `install_prelibrary` and then  `install_cdt`. Calling `install_cdt` from `install_prelibrary` is ok but `create_wallet_and_keys` gives error `command not found`. Why `create_wallet_and_keys` is not called on the remote host like other functions?
I want the very first function to be called on a remote host is `install_prelibrary` and then call other two from this function.
Please correct me.

Comment: You have a long string of variations of this question, and at every junction, you have been told that this approach is flawed. The simple and straightforward solution is to copy the script file to the remote host, then execute it there.

Comment: I tried this `SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; ‘bash -s’ < ~/shell/build/main.sh ; $(declare -f) ; install_prelibrary"` . Copying file but still it executes `create_wallet_and_keys` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing exactly what the generated script looks like, it's not really possible to troubleshoot this.

But I would instead break up your logic into a script which gets copied to the destination and executed there, and a simple script which does the copying and evaluation.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

script=$(cat <<\____HERE
install_prelibrary () {
  # Notice also refactoring; comments below
  if wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/download/v2.0.0/eosio_2.0.0-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb --no-check-certificate > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    : pass
  else
    rc=$?
    # Write errors to standard error, exit with an actual failure code
    printf "Error downloading Ubuntu Binary file\n" >&2
    exit $rc
  fi
  install_cdt
  create_wallet_and_keys
}

install_cdt(){
   #some commands
}
create_wallet_and_keys(){
   #some commands
}
____HERE
)
SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh); $script; install_prelibrary"
for i in ${!genesishost[*]} ; do
        printf "\t=========== node ${genesishost[i]} ===========\n\n"
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/"$password"}
        sshpass -p "$password" ssh -l "$username" "${genesishost[i]}" "${SCR}"
done
```

If you need to evaluate the functions locally, too, it's not too hard to have the script read itself; or simply store the code in an external file and `source` that as well as reading it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering your functions

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/shell/config.sh

install_cdt(){
   #some commands
}
create_wallet_and_keys(){
   #some commands
}

install_prelibrary () {
  wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/download/v2.0.0/eosio_2.0.0-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb --no-check-certificate > /dev/null 2>&1;
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                printf "\n\nError downloading Ubuntu Binary file\n\n"
                exit 0;
  else 
                install_cdt
                create_wallet_and_keys
  fi
}

SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; $(declare -f) ; install_prelibrary"
for i in ${!genesishost[*]} ; do
        printf "\t=========== node ${genesishost[i]} ===========\n\n"
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${password}}
        sshpass -p ${password} ssh -l ${username} ${genesishost[i]} "${SCR}"
done
```

This way they will be called beneath the functions themselves.